# everyone's and their

Tags: grammar

Which ones are correct and why?

1-Everyone should have a bed in their house.

2-Everyone should have a bed in their house**s**.

3-It's up to everyone's personal choice.

4-It's up to everyone's personal choice**s**.

Answer (score 3):

*Everyone* is a pronoun that means "each/every person." When you use it, you are talking about each individual within a group.

You might then see why the following are correct if you view the phrases as (unnaturally) more explicit about the individuals:

> *Each one person* should have a bed in their **house**.
>
> It's up to *each one person*'s personal **choice**.

That being said, the following would be valid if every person has multiple choices that they make:

> It's up to everyone's personal **choices**.